# Assign to a variable inside a closure a reference to the closure - does it leak?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at some JS ViewModel code that uses this pattern to be able to reference the outer closure in case whatever library changes the "this" pointer when invoking a function as a callback (gotta love JavaScript):

```
function FruitViewModel {
   var that = this; // <-- HERE

   this.someCallBack = function () {
      that.utilityFunction();
   };

   this.utilityFunction = function () { }
}
```

My question is: Will this cause a memory leak or will it be implementation specific? (e.g. if garbage is collected inside out versus outside in)

Edit: Please assume that at the point when the GC considers this object for collection nothing holds a reference to `someCallBack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector is clever enough to detect such cycle references. So it won't leak.

Comment: @Ivan: There are [articles such as this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/) which describe similar situations and might be confusing. But they refer to situations when there a reference to your object's member (`someCallback`, for example) is attached to a DOM element, which is long lived and isn't collected. Adding properties to DOM elements is more or less the same thing as creating globals, so it's natural that it won't allow collection. But it doesn't have much to do with closures, as the article is implying.

Answer (score 1):

In all JS engines, the object will not be collected until all functions declared in the parent function are no longer referenced.

I am not aware of any GC bugs relevant here.

Comment: You mean that it won't be collected until someone holds, say, a reference to `someCallBack`? Ok, lets assume that's already the case - will the JS GC cope with the cyclic reference in `that`? It's not the classical A -> B -> A , but A -> A -> A.

Comment: Once there are no references to `this` or `someCallback` or `utilityFunction`, `this` and the closure will be collectible.

Comment: Ok, but there is still a reference to `this` stored in `that`.

Comment: @IvanZlatev: The entire closure, including `that`, is not referenced.  The GC can handle a circular reference.